Is sum of vector spaces a vector space
I have to check that set $\cup_{i \in I} Z_i $ is a vector space when these conditions holds:
-for some $i_0 \in I$, $Z_{i_0}$ is a vector space,
-for all $i \in I$, $Z_i$ is closed, convex, contains zero and $Z_i \subset Z_{i_0}$.
Is there any fast way or something to notice to confirm it?

Is $\bigcup_{i \in I} Z_i $ not equal to $Z_{i_0}$ ?

Since $Z_i \subset Z_{i_0}$, we know that $\cup_{i\in I}Z_i = Z_{i_0}$, which is itself a vector space. This doesn't use the other facts about the $Z_i$s though, which seems off to me.
